# Best way to implement the following on android or ios

Tags: android, iphone, ios, ipad

I am creating a tablet app (both iOS and Android)
I have a menu system in which i am displaying different content for different menu.One menu contains Shopping malls
this contain detail such as
1. Photographs 
2. Videos
3. Text

We want this application to be run offline , so all data is stored on the Tablet. But at times we need that the data can be updated also.

One of the option that we thought of using is 
1. HTML files and display the HTML files (Problem - Not getting the required fluidity and customisability)
2. Hardcoding all the data (This has the problem of updating the new data , I DO NOT WANT TO UPDATE THE DATA PROGRAMATICALLY)

what is the best way to implement this ? using webviews or something else ?

Comment: "I DO NOT WANT TO UPDATE THE DATA PROGRAMATICALLY" then how ?

Comment: @njzk2 probably through a database , i do not want to hard code the data so that every time i want a change i have to open the sdk and make the changes and again publish the app and download it on the device ...

Comment: so you don't want to update the program, but the data could be updated by the program, i.e., programatically. your formulation is odd.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't know about android, but ios I would use core data to store the data and I would use a web service for updates.  The client can check the web service to see if updates are available and then download them if they are.  Your client code can then update core data objects based on these updates.

The same approach would suit android, I just don't know the implementation details for android.

For ios some libraries such as AFNetworking and JSONkit would prove useful.

Answer (score 0):

I'd work to the following:

1. Write the app so that on first launch a network connection is
   required and download your data to an SQLite database / CoreData for
   iOS
2. Check for a valid network connection on each launch, or as a service, and if present contact your service and check for the last updated time. If this is different than that of the device, update the local databases. If there is no network, then perform no check.
3. Proceed as normal

Answer (score 0):

If you want to develop this app with one tool use a framework like Titanium. Else you can design a good database  in SQLite, it can work for Android and iOS and you can update with a server database throught webservice for example.

Answer (score 0):

You could potentially use a third-party tool like Phonegap, which allow you to deploy across different mobile platforms using standard web development tools like CSS/HTML/JavaScript.

At a high-level, one approach would be as follows: 
- Develop a client application using CSS/HTML/Javascript and leverage APIs exposed by PhoneGap that provide a single access point to local storage across the different mobile platforms. 
- PhoneGap creates a native app for each individual mobile platform, and stores the web client directly on the device.  Because the client HTML/CSS/JS is stored on the device, it is available while offline to be rendered using the device's browser. 
- At run time, you can check if the device has internet access and pull in updates via RESTful web service, or simply load from local storage if not.

It's definitely worth looking into if the functionality doesn't require extensive device capabilities or access to features like a graphics engine.

http://phonegap.com/